# Grouping multiple deferred JS script imports in HTML header into one

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

My code currently looks something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

  <head>
    ...
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/master.css">  <!-- One stylesheet to import them all. -->

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js" defer></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/collapsibles.js" defer></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/imports.js" defer></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/topnav.js" defer></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    ...
```

and the issue is that these header script imports appear in very many places. This results in a lot of duplicated code, and whenever I want to add a new script, I have to add the  `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/new.js" defer></script>` into every `.html` file header manually. I've recently found a very nice solution to this with stylesheets, where I now import one `master.css` stylesheet in all `.html` file headers, and then I can add new styles into `master.css`, which looks something like this:

```
/* Register all base website imports here. */
@import url(base.css);
@import url(home.css);
@import url(topnav.css);
@import url(containers.css);
...
```

My question is, is there any JavaScript equivalent for grouping HTML header imports (similar to the one I've shown above)? I've tried `$.getScript("test.js");`, but I don't think it's executing the script in the same way the `<head>` tags are doing. It also seems to work strangely with the `defer` command..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with a vanilla JS I would make like that:

```
// in index.html
<script src="./index.js"></script>

//in index.js
let scriptEle = document.createElement("script");
scriptEle.setAttribute("src", "./t.js");
scriptEle.setAttribute("async", "false");
scriptEle.setAttribute("defer", true);
document.head.appendChild(scriptEle);

let scriptEle1 = document.createElement("script");
scriptEle1.setAttribute("src", "./t1.js");
scriptEle1.setAttribute("async", "false");
scriptEle1.setAttribute("defer", true);
document.head.appendChild(scriptEle1);

// sure, you may refactor and use an array of src urls
```

Now you need to modify only one JS file instead of each html files

Comment: =) Hope it helps you